# Help me decipher notation! $_*$ vs $^*$ Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am reading through MSc course notes in Algebraic Topology where we use " * " in defining:

> If $\gamma : M \rightarrow N$ is a map of sets then there is an induced group homomorphism

$\gamma_* :A[M] \rightarrow A[N]$ with $\gamma_*(f)(g) = \sum f(x)$

That is, $\gamma_*$ takes $a_1x_1 + ...$ to $a_1\gamma(x_1) + ...$

So this is all fine until we are introduced Simplicical sets, where we are given structure maps between sequences of sets:

> $a^* : K_n \rightarrow K_m$ for each order preserving map $a : [m] \rightarrow [n]$ such that $ (id_[m])^* = id_{K_m}$

Question: What is the difference between $_*$ and $^*$? May sound like a silly question but it has confused me and I have no-one to ask.

Comment: Generally, subscripts refer to *covariance* and superscripts refer to *contravariance*. The assignments $M \mapsto A[M]$ and $\gamma \mapsto \gamma_*$ define a covariant functor, meaning that $(-)_*$ preserves the direction of a morphism. The assignments $[m] \mapsto K_m$ and $a \mapsto a^*$ define a contravariant functor, meaning $(-)^*$ reverses the direction of a morphism.

Comment: The location of the $*$ is just telling us whether the associated functor is behaving covariantly or contravariantly.  Note that your $\gamma_*$ is a map from something involving $M$ to something involving $N$, whereas $a^*$ seems to have flipped things around: it's a map from something involving $n$ to something involving $m$.  We use upper stars for these contravariant things (which flip the order of composition).

Comment: Thank you all for your rapid responses! That really clears up a lot of my misunderstandings, I will go and read more into contravarient and covariant functors now before continuing my reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the direction of the starred map.

Given some morphism $\alpha:X\to Y$ for some structures $X, Y$ (for instance topological spaces, or varieties, or manifolds), if $\alpha$ induces some map $f$ between algebraic structures $B(X)$ and $B(Y)$ defined from $X$ and $Y$ (for instance, homology groups, sheaves or differential forms), then usually, it's called $f_*$ if it goes form $A(X)$ to $A(Y)$, and it's called $f^*$ if it goes from $A(Y)$ to $A(X)$.